# try to send email using mail function in php

Tags: php

```
$to = 'others@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $from = "my@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;

    mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers))

        echo 1;
    else{
echo 2;
}
```

I have tried this and it is not on localhost.it is not working.is there any way to show what is the error ? is there any need to be change the setting in php.ini?

Comment: try first to var_dump(mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers)); it will return boolean value. If it's false, you are missing something.

Comment: yes it return false.but how can i know what is missing?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail

Comment: not worked for me

Comment: is there any problem in above code?